# Compare multiple columns within 2 database tables based on current_post.id - MySQL/Flask

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

I am building a jobs board where users can apply for jobs. Employers who have posted the job are able to click a button and see which candidates have applied and which candidates match the requirements of the specific job.

I have 2 database tables called job_requirements and Applicant. The job_requirements table contains fields requirement_1, requirement_2, requirement_3, requirement_4, requirement_5, requirement_6 and the Applicant table contains the fields skill_1, skill_2, skill_3, skill_4, skill_5, and skill_6.

Below is my code:
current_post.id is the id number of the specific record (job) saved in the job_requirements table.

What I have tried to do is get the current_post id and then compare it against the applicant table job_id as they should be the same. job_id is a field within the applicant database table that shows which job each applicant has applied for.

Therefore I should obtain the records of all the applicants that have applied for that specific job. Once I have this I compare the skills fields with the requirements fields of that specific job.
The resulting records should be only the applicants whose skills match the requirements of that specific job.

```
@app.route("/post/<id>/eligible_applicants", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def matches(id):
    current_post = Job_Requirements.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    if current_post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)
    same_id = Applicant.query.filter(Applicant.job_id==current_post.id)
    for records in same_id:
        sql = "SELECT Applicant.* FROM Applicant JOIN job__requirements WHERE Applicant.skill_1 IN (job__requirements.requirement_1, job__requirements.requirement_2, job__requirements.requirement_3, job__requirements.requirement_4, job__requirements.requirement_5, job__requirements.requirement_6) AND Applicant.skill_2 IN (job__requirements.requirement_1, job__requirements.requirement_2, job__requirements.requirement_3, job__requirements.requirement_4, job__requirements.requirement_5, job__requirements.requirement_6) AND Applicant.skill_3 IN (job__requirements.requirement_1, job__requirements.requirement_2, job__requirements.requirement_3, job__requirements.requirement_4, job__requirements.requirement_5, job__requirements.requirement_6) AND Applicant.skill_4 IN (job__requirements.requirement_1, job__requirements.requirement_2,job__requirements.requirement_3, job__requirements.requirement_4, job__requirements.requirement_5, job__requirements.requirement_6) AND Applicant.skill_5 IN (job__requirements.requirement_1, job__requirements.requirement_2, job__requirements.requirement_3, job__requirements.requirement_4, job__requirements.requirement_5, job__requirements.requirement_6) AND Applicant.skill_6 IN (job__requirements.requirement_1, job__requirements.requirement_2, job__requirements.requirement_3, job__requirements.requirement_4, job__requirements.requirement_5, job__requirements.requirement_6)"
        result = db.engine.execute(sql)
        return render_template('matches.html', id=current_post.id, title='Eligible Applicants', result=result)
```

here is the code for my applicant and job_requirements tables:

```
class Applicant(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'applicant' 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, auto_increment=True)
    skill_1 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    skill_2 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    skill_3 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    skill_4 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    skill_5 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    skill_6 = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    validation_flag=db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('job__requirements.id'), nullable=False) 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Applicant('{self.skill_1}', '{self.skill_2}','{self.skill_3}', '{self.skill_4}','{self.skill_5}','{self.skill_6}','{self.validation_flag}')"
```

```
class Job_Requirements(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_posted=db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    job_title = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    company = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    sector = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    employment_type = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    requirement_1 = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    requirement_2 = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    requirement_3 = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    requirement_4 = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    requirement_5 = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    requirement_6 = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    #requirement=db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    #paintings = db.relationship("Applicant", backref="Job_Requirements") 
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Job_Requirements('{self.date_posted}', '{self.job_title}', '{self.company}', '{self.location}', '{self.employment_type}', '{self.sector}','{self.description}', '{self.requirement_1}', '{self.requirement_2}', '{self.requirement_3}', '{self.requirement_4}', '{self.requirement_5}', '{self.requirement_6}')"
```

Comment: At its heart, this is a problem of poor (de-normalised) schema design. Until that's fixed, there are no good solutions.

Comment: hey, im new to programming so not great at all. I realise that the route code has a lot of massive errors and is not normalised at all. When I print the variable same_id it is able to get the specific records. However, to query these records is confusing to me.